# I can't get basic bxslider to work

Tags: jquery

**Okay, so don't kill me, I"m new to jquery and bxsliders, but I"m about to punt this whole thing and need a saviour.  I think all my files are in the right places...I just can't figure this out.

Simple problem: trying to get a slider to work:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('slider1').bxSlider();
$('slider2').bxSlider();
});
</script>

<div class="sliders">

<h3>Slideshow 1</h3>
<ul id="slider1">
<li><img src="images/JT.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/RW.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/WJ.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/DF.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/BE.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/JH.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

<h3>Slideshow 2</h3>
<ul id="slider2">
<li><img src="images/JT.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/RW.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/WJ.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/DF.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/BE.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/JH.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

</div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing `#` in the selector. `$('#slider1').bxSlider();`

Comment: @PSL Should have wrote that up as an answer!

Comment: Downvoters should explain **why** they are downvoting, partcularly for new users to the site. I personally don't understand why this deserved a downvote given that clear, formatted code was provided and the problem was well explained, effort made by the OP, etc etc.

Comment: Don't down vote Let the new user learn.

Comment: THat didn't solve the problem....I actually had that originally, but started 'flipping bits' to see if anything was coded incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Read Documentation [**# id-selector**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slider1').bxSlider();
       ^ // added # tag for id-selector
    $('#slider2').bxSlider();
       ^ // added # tag for id-selector
});
```

[**Learn jQuery**](http://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: I WISH that was it....I've changed it and no luck.  But thanks, I'll read up on id-selectors.  :(

Comment: @user2860816 can u make a fiddle .