# Error: Invalid Selector - tab! Please, check whether the used ID or CSS Class name is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqxgrid

when i am working with  displaying JqxGrid in Jquery UI tabs.  i'm getting above error as **Error: Invalid Selector - tab! Please, check whether the used ID or CSS Class name is correct.**
here is my code:

```
<body class="default">

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabsss">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabssss">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab">

  </div>
  <div id="tabsss">

  </div>
  <div id="tabssss">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

calling JqxGrid:-

```
$("tab").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: '100%',
                source: dataAdapter,                
                pageable: true,
                autoheight: true,
                sortable: true,
                altrows: true,
                enabletooltips: true,
                editable: true,
                selectionmode: 'multiplecellsadvanced',
                columns: [
                  { text: 'Product Name', columngroup: 'ProductDetails', datafield: 'ProductName', width: 250 },
                  { text: 'Quantity per Unit', columngroup: 'ProductDetails', datafield: 'QuantityPerUnit', cellsalign: 'right', align: 'right', width: 200 },
                  { text: 'Unit Price', columngroup: 'ProductDetails', datafield: 'UnitPrice', align: 'right', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2', width: 200 },
                  { text: 'Units In Stock', datafield: 'UnitsInStock', cellsalign: 'right', cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer, width: 100 },
                  { text: 'Discontinued', columntype: 'checkbox', datafield: 'Discontinued' }
                ],
                columngroups: [
                    { text: 'Product Details', align: 'center', name: 'ProductDetails' }
                ]
            });
```

i'm new to jquery so can you  please  give the solution to my task?
thanking in Advance!

Comment: `$("tab")` implies a `<tab>` tag. You need `$("#tab")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't get basic bxslider to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261331/i-cant-get-basic-bxslider-to-work)